# jquery Ajax call on second onclick is not working

Tags: jquery

when first click on jquery working fine.When i clcik the second time with different URL is not working ...could you please tell me what is wrong?

```
$('#idResult').live('click', function(e){
 $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
   e.preventDefault();
var url= $('#idStore').val();
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            contentType: "text/xml",
            dataType: "xml",
           success: function(xml) {
$('#basicTable').append("<tr><td><+$(this).find('attributes attribute[name="NAME"]').text()+"<</td></tr>");
}
});
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you edit your id with class and then try using this code!
I hope works!

```
$('.idResult').live('click', function(e) {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
e.preventDefault();
var url = $('.idStore').val();
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    contentType: "text/xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        $('#basicTable').append("<tr><td><" + $(this).find('attributes attribute[name="NAME"]').text() + "></td></tr>");
    }
});
return false;
```

});

Comment: it is working fine.because i missed out in the logic.thanks for answering